# Switching connection encryption on the fly (browser padlock)

Tags: tls, web-browser

On Youtube, the connection is encrypted (green padlock). However I found myself in a situation that when I click on for example a comment that contains a URL to a different website (on which the connection is not encrypted), then the padlock on Youtube changes to yellow.

[image: Screenshot of browser saying that connection to youtube.com is not secure.].

Also, when I`m on some website that isn't secure, If that website has, for example, a Paypal link on it, when I click on that link (that is secure) the page that had no green padlock, suddenly has one.

Is this a problem? Can this become a problem? Is the user becoming vulnerable to some attacks, and if so, which one? Can you explain why the padlock changes like this.

Tested on Firefox Quantum (Windows 7) and Chrome 63 (Ubuntu 16:10).

Comment: If you click on a link to Paypal, you go to Paypal. Since your connection to Paypal is encrypted, you get a green lock. Where you came from doesn't matter.

Comment: Go to chrome menu-->More Tools-->Developer Tools. then Click on the "Security" tab. It will show you more details about what is the issue. The issue is probably that the main URL is over https but the page contains links to other sites/scripts over http. E.g., there is some src="http://blahblah" within the html for the main page.